# SSL Error (bad handshake) with valid certificate | Elasticsearch & Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, ssl, https

I am passing data to Elasticsearch (ES) through a Python script. First, I secured ES with a self-signed certificate and everything works as expected. Then, I switched to a more trusted certificate (Let's Encrypt). Note, that I can reach my ES cluster without any problems. The Let's Encrypt cert is trusted by my browser + by an application that is talking to ES, no problem. But when I try to pass data from my Python script to ES with the new certificate, I get following error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

I would have expected this error with a self signed cert but not with Let's encrypt. The only way I can avoid it, is by changing the settings to `verify=False`, which is no long-term solution.

Before I received the error message mentioned above, I got following error: 
`elasticsearch.exceptions.SSLError: ConnectionError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)) caused by: SSLError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777))`

**I found a workaround for this by doing** `pip install requests`. **However, afterwards I receive the first error I mentioned (bad handshake).** I know that this means that the certificate is not trusted. But how can this be, if it works for a self-signed cert but not for a Let's Encrypt cert that is trusted by a browser and an app? E.g. if I call ES on https://my-IP:9200, no warning is given by my browser, while a warning will be given with the self-signed cert.

**Some additional info**

- python3
- urllib3 1.25.7
- certifi 2019.9.11
- Ubuntu 18.04

So, basically everything is up-to-date. I also tried a suggested solution by downgrading certifi and/or urllib3, but it doesn't work. One suggestion is to downgrade urllib3 below version 1.25 (but as I said, it doesn't work in my case).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install certificate first, and then use it in connection to `Elasticsearch` with `Python`

```
host = 'mydomain.com:9200'

client = Elasticsearch(host, http_auth=('admin', 'pass'), scheme="https", use_ssl=True, ca_certs='C:/my_path/CertificateFile.cer.pem', port=443)


try:
    info = json.dumps(client.info(), indent=4)
    print ("Elasticsearch client info():", info)

except exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
    print ("\nElasticsearch info() ERROR:", err)
    print ("\nThe client host:", host, "is invalid or cluster is not running")
    client = None
```

Response:

```
> Elasticsearch client info(): {
>     "name": "my_name",
>     "cluster_name": "my_cluster_name",
>     "cluster_uuid": "fBRShbkSRy2vcfQJZsojGA",
>     "version": {
>         "number": "7.3.0",
>         "build_flavor": "default",
>         "build_type": "tar",
>         "build_hash": "de777fa",
>         "build_date": "2019-07-24T18:30:11.767338Z",
>         "build_snapshot": false,
>         "lucene_version": "8.1.0",
>         "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
>         "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
>     },
>     "tagline": "You Know, for Search" }
```

**elasticsearch.yml:**

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.ml.enabled: false
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
```